# Deployed azure virtual application webrole not compiled

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have spent the last couple of days getting an application deployed to auze. All is looking good but I have gotten stuck on an issue with virtual applications.

Within my servicedefinition file I have

```
 <Sites>
  <Site name="Web" physicalDirectory="D:\@code\Web">
    <VirtualApplication name="API" physicalDirectory="D:\@code\API"></VirtualApplication>
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
      <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="Https" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

Both applications are deployed and the virtual appliction is created however I can't get the api application to run. I rdp onto the server and took a look around. The API project isn't being compiled, Basically all of the .cs files are in the root of the siteroot > 1

Is there an extra step I need to do to fix this?

Any assistance would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the WebRole project (`..Site name='Web'...`) is "compiled".

All rest of the sites you define, including Virtual Applications are just copied. So you need to point the `physicalDirectory` to a locally deployed/compiled app folder. You can for example create a Publish Profile for your API project that deploys to local file system. Then specify the target folder of that deployment for `physicalDirectory` in the `VirtualApplication` definition.

There is some documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx). However it is not explicitly mentioned that it works out of the box for a WebSite projects and not Web Application projects! It will work for WebSite project out of the box, because the deployment model for WebSite project is just `xcopy deployment`.

Apparently there are very few people who do WebSite projects nowadays. Most of us do Web Application projects. So, in the case of Web Application we must not point the `physicalDirectory` to the project folder, but rather to a deployment folder for that project.

If someone is confused - here the official documentation on [Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx).